# The arclength parametrization of $\gamma(t)=(2t,(t-1)^2,3t^3)$

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, arc-length

Find the arclength paramztrization of the curve $$\gamma(t)=(2t,(t-1)^2,3t^3), t\in \mathbb R$$

---

We have $$s(t)=\int_{t_0}^t\|\dot\gamma(u)\|du=\int_{t_0}^t\sqrt{4+4(u-1)^2+(9u^2)^2}du$$
I couldn't calculate it.

Any help is appreciated !

Comment: That function has no elementary primitive. Is that the whole problem? Or is it part of a larger problem?

Comment: Thanks you for your comment Sir.                                                                         
  The problem is :   1. give the arclength parametrization of $\gamma$  2.Calculate the curvature and the torsion.

Comment: I am ready to bet that $z=3t^2$

Comment: For future reference, you should make sure you know how to find curvature and torsion using the chain rule, without ever trying to reparametrize explicitly by arclength.

Comment: Okey, Thanks a lot all of you !

Answer (score 2):

I am almost sure that there is a typo in the question. It *could* be
$$\gamma(t)=(2t,(t-1)^2,3t^\color{red}{2})$$ If this is the case, then
$$L=\int \sqrt{40 t^2-8 t+8}\,dt$$
$$t=\frac {u+1}{10}\implies L=\frac{1}{5 \sqrt{10}}\int\sqrt{u^2+19}\,du$$
$$u=\sqrt{19} \sinh (v)\implies L=\frac{19}{5 \sqrt{10}}\int \cosh^2(v)\,dv$$

Now, this one is very simple. When done, go back to $u$ and then to $t$.

Comment: There's no typo in the exercice but your answer helped me !Thanks a lot !

Comment: @M-S. Then, it is a big monster ! Cheers :-)